# Is the scaling performed in a Right way for further use of the multiple linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, normalize

My data consists of variables such as Profit,R&D spend,Administrative spend and Marketing spend. I need to perform multiple linear regression to find the profit of these startups based on their spending. I got **stuck in standardising the data** using R. I used the scaling function for all the columns individually and put it into a new dataframe. I'm new to data science and need to ensure whether the scaling technique performed, (i.e) to have `mean=0` and `sd=1`, is right or any other way to proceed ahead?

```r
startup<-read.csv(file.choose())
View(startup)
install.packages("mnormt")
library(psych)
pairs.panels(startup)
attach(startup)
model.startup<-lm(Profit~R.D.Spend+Administration+Marketing.Spend)
summary(model.startup)

library(car)
vif(model.startup)

range(R.D.Spend)
range(Administration)
range(Marketing.Spend)
range(Profit)

Profitscale<-scale(Profit)
View(Profitscale)
summary(Profitscale)
sd(Profitscale)

RDscale<-scale(R.D.Spend)
summary(RDscale)
sd(RDscale)

Adscale<-scale(Administration)
Marscale<-scale(Marketing.Spend)

Scaled_startup<-data.frame(Profitscale,RDscale,Adscale,Marscale)
View(Scaled_startup)
pairs.panels(Scaled_startup)
attach(Scaled_startup)

model.startup1<-lm(Profitscale~RDscale+Adscale+Marscale)
summary(model.startup1)
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you seek recommendations for fitting statistical models, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: Thank you so much MrFlick for your appropriate recommendation. It will help me alot to improve my skills in R - data science.